# I want to create a java list that checks the items in an object?

Tags: java, list, return

I have a function that returns an object with parameters like so:

```
public static class Classname getClassName(Object o){
......
......



return new Classname(a,b,c,d,e)


}
```

so i want to create a list, that takes these objects and checks to see if they were returned already, if they were i want it to create a new object, if not it can return it

would i go about it like so:

```
final List<Classname> name = new ArrayList<Classname>();

how do i put the object into the list?
```

Comment: You're saying you want a cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling a cache to limit instantiation of your objects is not difficult, but the best implementation might depend on your class.

Here's a simple way:

- Implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` for `Classname`.
- Add it to a Map as a key and value

Like this:

```
private static final Map<Classname, Classname> cache = new HashMap<Classname, Classname>();
public static Classname getClassName(Object o){
   Classname newC = new Classname(a, b, ...);
   Classname oldC = cache.get(newC);
   if ( oldC == null ) {
       cache.put(newC, newC);
       return newC;
   } else {
       return oldC;
   }
}
```

But as you can see, in this case you have to make a Classname just to look it up in the cache!  This pattern works better when you have a unique key (such as a String "name") that identifies an object in the cache.  Then you can use that as your key type for the map.

If you just want to use a list you need to implement `equals` (and `hashCode`), and then you can just do this:

```
Classname newC = new Classname(a, b, ...);
for ( Classname existing : name ) {
    if ( newC.equals(existing) ) {
        return existing;
    }
}
name.add(newC);
return newC;
```

Comment: although this is a great answer, I want to use a list for this instance

Comment: Thanks, the map seems much more practical and safe!

Answer (score 0):

Add typically adds objects to a list.  In this case...  `name.add(o);`

`for( Object o: name ) { System.out.println(o); }`

Comment: ok so now that i have done this, i want to iterate through the list to see if any of the items in the list were returned already

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29):

> add
>
> public boolean add(Object o)
>
> Appends the specified element to the end of
> this list.
>
> Parameters: o - element
> to be appended to this list.
>
> Returns:
> true (as per the general contract of
> Collection.add).